# assign na value to Pandas dataframe doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
dataSource[(dataSource['age_at_extraction_date']<0)]['age_at_extraction_date'] = np.nan
```

Hello everyone, I am trying to assign na value to all the data whose age is recorded as a negative value.

The above sentence runs without errors & warnings but takes no effect as well.

Can anyone give me a hand tell me why this sentense doesn't take effect?

Thanks in advance for anyone who willing to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
dataSource['age_at_extraction_date'][dataSource['age_at_extraction_date']<0] = np.nan
```